# way to warn developers they are on Production site

Tags: web-applications, production

We have a web app deployed in several environments (Dev, QA, etc.) as well as Production.  Ironically enough, the non-production sites have prominent markings saying what environment it is, but Production does not (for obvious reasons).  The danger is that a developer will do something on production thinking that they are in some other environment.  Of course, self-discipline is your friend here (close Prod as soon as you're done) but is there anything systematic we can put in place to help us out that will not affect the user experience in Prod?

Comment: Don't allow developers on the production systems?  (this is not a joke answer.  if you have dev/qa/etc. machines, it should be extremely unusual for a developer to be on production.)

Comment: If your developers require a production environment on a regular basis to do their job, that's a smell that there is something lacking in your development environment. Ask the developers *why* they need the production environment for development and then use that answer to fix the development environment.

Comment: @Asaph, maybe they want to see if they can reproduce an error?

Comment: What about using GreaseMonkey on each dev machine?  That way the code itself is not affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### .NET

Check the requester's IP address and see if it falls within your private subnet.

```
if (Request.UserHostAddress.StartsWith("192.168.1."))
{
    // show control
}
```

Comment: Making production behave differently than development in code is a bad practice, even if you think it's a totally benign case. Your code should be completely agnostic to what environment it's running in.

Comment: @Asaph, that's a fair enough observation, but it belongs on the original post, not mine since you are suggesting that the OP **NOT** move forward with what he wanted to do. I'm only answering his question, not opining on whether or not it's good practice.

Answer (score 5):

Promoted to answer, from comment:

Don't allow developers on the production systems This is not a joke answer. if you have dev/qa/etc. machines, it should be extremely unusual for a developer to be on production.  So unusual that they will 'quake in fear' when they are on production boxes.  I've done this for > 25 years, and I still get that fear. (it's a good thing)

Comment: Apart from the obvious pitfalls from a development perspective, allowing developers onto a production site risks infringing the law in the UK and much of Europe, if it permits access to customer details (Data Protection Act etc).

Comment: So who does a final double-check after a push to make sure that nothing major was screwed up?

Comment: Validators or Integrators (or both)

Comment: well I guess those of us who are the designer, developer, tester, validator, integrator, and helpdesk are just doomed to "bad practice".

Comment: @Brad - I've run the gamut, but always had 'the fear'

Answer (score 1):

### .NET with machines in an AD domain

Check the requester's host name and see if it ends with your internal domain name.

```
if (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostAddress).HostName.EndsWith(".myIntenalDomain.local"))
{
    // show control
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with 'close prod as soon as your done with it'.  However there are cases where developers are constantly requiring access to prod servers.  If you are that worried then force developers to use a specific machine (other than their own) to make changes to prod.  This gives a physical cue since they have to change machines that they better be careful.